# jQuery UI: Slider inside of a Tab?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want my tab content area to have a vertical scrollbar to the right using the jQuery UI Slider API. The tab content area will have a fixed height, and the vertical overflow needs to cause a jQuery UI Slider to appear to scroll through the content.

The specific issue I'm having trouble with is how to structure the HTML and what to style each element with in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use slider as a scroll bar?

Normally, you should simply pick a scroll bar plugin and go with it, instead of trying to make a control to do what it is not designed for.

[This page](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/) lists a few jQuery plugins for scoll bars. Here are a few of them:

- [jScrollPene](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) ([demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html))
- [jQuery Custom Content Scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) ([demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html))
- [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)

But, if you insist using jQuery UI Slider, [someone](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/vertical-scrollbar-using-jquery-ui-slider/) has already made this work, with a [demo page](http://www.simonbattersby.com/demos/vertical_scrollbar_demo_1_basic.htm).

Comment: I thought sliders were meant to be used as scroll bars. Thanks for clearing that up.